# Round time to nearest 15min interval in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, rounding

I've an excel spreadsheet with a column which has the date and time of a particular event. I would like to round this to the nearest 15 minute interval so that I can count the total number of events in this period. What is the best way to do do the rounding?

Comment: Always rounding up or either way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you said you also want the date, how about this:

`= (ROUND((A1 * 1440) / 15, 0) * 15) / 1440`

Assuming that A1 has the date/time value you want. This takes advantage of the fact that date/time columns in Excel are just numbers (integer portion is the date, fractional portion is the time)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to round to the Nearest 15:

Assuming your time is in cell A2

We'll put our new time into B2:

```
B2 =TIME(HOUR(A2), ROUND((MINUTE(A2)/60)*4, 0) * 15, 0)
```

If you wanted to always round up or down you replace ROUND with ROUNDUP or ROUNDDOWN

Answer (score 7):

simple:

- if rounded up =CEILING(A1,"00:15")
- if rounded down =FLOOR(A1, "00:15")

Where A1 is the difference between the two time. It can be a reference or calculations:
`=CEILING(C2-B2,"00:15")`, where C2 is the end time and B2 is the start time.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution and also the easiest to read.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

mround takes time values as strings, so you can use

```
=mround(a1,"0:15")
```

which I think is the shortest and clearest method.

Answer (score 3):

Date and time rounded to nearest 15-minute period (you can always round up/round down using something like INT):

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1))+TIME(HOUR(B1), ROUND(MINUTE(B1)/15,0)*15, 0)
```

Assuming cell B1 contains the date time to be rounded. This will return the number in typical serial date fashion (e.g. 39846.64444 = 02/02/2009 15:28) and you need to format your result cell as a date/time to see the value (as with all solutions to this problem). Showing date and time together is not a standard Date or Time format, you need a Custom format to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just found a helpful function, MROUND, which is available in Excel 2007 and as an Analysis add-in.

Assuming your time is in B2, with a number like 8.43 to represent 8 hours, 25.8 minutes:

```
=MROUND(MOD(B2,1)*60,15)
```

the MOD(B2,1) would extract the fractional 0.43; the *60 would convert to 25.8; and the MROUND would round you to the nearest multiple of 15, namely 30.

Comment: Less typing:  =MROUND(a2, TIME(0,15,0)).  You can change the 0,15,0 to any multiple of rounding.  For instance if you want the nearest hour: =MROUND(a2, TIME(1,0,0))).  The time function is (hour,minute,second).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have 2 date-times and you want to find the total and round up to the nearest 15 minutes:

```
A1 = 7/10/2014 16:10    
A2 = 7/10/2014 17:49
```

First get the total in decimal hours:

```
A3:   =(A2-A1)*24
```

Then you can round up to the nearest quarter hour:

```
A4:  =Ceiling(A3, .25)
```

Or do it all on one cell:

```
A3:  =Ceiling((A2-A1)*24, .25)
```

Comment: Definitely the most straightforward answer here.  Also use Floor(<val>, 0.25) to round down to the nearest 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If time is in cell A1:

```
=ROUND(A1*(24*60/15),0)/(24*60/15)
```

(Rounding to nearest 15 minute increment)

or

```
=INT(A1*(24*60/15),0)/(24*60/15)
```

(Rounding down to last 15 minute increment)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler ??

=B2-MOD(B2,15/24/60)

Knowing that for Excel 1 day = 24 hrs = 1,
15/24/60 (= 0.0104166666666667) is the numeric equivalent equivalent of 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
=CEILING(((MOD(D16-C16;1))*24);0,25)
```

It calculates the time difference of two different times C16 and D16 in hours first. Then rounds up.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.  Rounds to the closest 15 minute interval.

```
= ROUND(B2 * 24 * 4, 0) / 4 / 24
```