# How to round time to nearest hour in Excel?

Tags: excel, time

How to round time to nearest hour in Excel, for example:

```
67:45:00 will be 68:00:00
and
53:14:00 will be 53:00:00
```

regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372924/round-time-to-nearest-15min-interval-in-excel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round minute down to nearest quarter hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `MROUND` function like this

`=MROUND(A1,"1:00")`

Comment: Hey.. is this related to any other config in the spreadsheet? It rounds too high in my setting.

Comment: Same as `=MROUND(A1,1/24)`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming the time is in A1 this will round to closest hour.

```
=ROUND(A1*24,0)/24
```

---

- Using *`ROUNDDOWN`* will force 67:45:00 to 67:00:00
- Using *`ROUNDUP`* Will force 67:45:00 to 68:00:00

Same formula, change:

- 24 to 48 for half hours.
- 24 to 96 for quarters

  ---

If you are grouping hourly in a 24 hour span but the date is included in the time stamp, use the same formula but subtract the datevalue after:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1*24;0)/24-INT(A1)
```

This is useful if you want to see at what time of day something peaks over a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Transform it to hours (5h 15m = 5.25h) then round it

if you only have it as a string use

```
=if(round(mid(A1;4;2);0)>29;mid(A1;1;2)+1&":00:00";mid(A1;1;2)&":00:00")
```

i use round to convert the minutes into a number

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to convert times to the nearest quarter hour.  I used the following sequence of formulas, which seemed to work:

=SUM(A1*24*60)  -  this converts the time to minutes

=MOD(B1,15)    -  this finds the minutes since the last quarter hour

=IF(C1>7,15-C1,-C1)   -  minutes needed to round up or down to nearest quarter hour

=SUM(D1/(24*60))  - converts the adjustment needed from minutes back to a days

=SUM(A1+E1)     - this is the original time adjusted up or down to the nearest quarter hour